# Calculating percentage of left over cost displaying result as NaN

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to show the percentage which is left after number1 has subtracted from number. The values I am calling contain a **£ symbol** and when running the code I get the result of **NaN** I guess this is to do with the **£** sign as when removed the percentage shows. Anyone have any idea how I can fix this please ? I have been trying for hours with no luck :( Thanks in advance.

```
double number;  
double number1;  
double result;  

double.TryParse(SelectedQuoteForEditing.JobPrice, out number);  
double.TryParse(lblRate.Content.ToString().ToString(), out number1);  

var left = Math.Round((number - number1) / number * 100, 2);  

result = left;  

ERGPerc.Content = result.ToString("P") + "%";
```

Comment: If you divide 0 by 0 you get Nan as result. So if number = 0 and number1 = 0 you get in this situation. I would add a check to see if number is not 0. number1 being 0 is not a disaster

Comment: I said in the description I had checked without the £ in both values and it returns the percentage fine. Both values are not 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, `double.NaN` is a result of `0.0 / 0.0`.

```
0.0 / 0.0 == double.NaN
```

that's why both `number` and `number1` are `0.0`. It means that

```
double.TryParse(SelectedQuoteForEditing.JobPrice, out number);   
double.TryParse(lblRate.Content.ToString().ToString(), out number1);
```

either `SelectedQuoteForEditing.JobPrice` is `0.0` or invalid (say, empty string) and the same for `lblRate.Content.ToString().ToString()`.

Check the value `double.TryParse` returns:

```
if (double.TryParse(SelectedQuoteForEditing.JobPrice, out number) &&  
    double.TryParse(lblRate.Content.ToString(), out number1) {

  var left = Math.Round((number - number1) / number * 100, 2);  
  ERGPerc.Content = left.ToString("P") + "%"; 
}  
else {
  // at least one value is invalid
}
```

**Edit:** If you want to parse *currency*, say `GB` ones (see `£150.00` in the comments), you have to let the system know about it:

```
double.TryParse(SelectedQuoteForEditing.JobPrice, 
  NumberStyles.Any,                    // allow currency symbols
  CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"), // which currency? GB 
  out number);    

double.TryParse(lblRate.Content.ToString(), 
  NumberStyles.Any,                    // allow currency symbols
  CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"), // which currency? GB 
  out number1);
```

otherwise the `Parse` fails (what `£` means? It doesn't correct part of floating point value!) you'll get `0.0` for `number` and `number1` and `double.NaN` on `(number - number1) / number` execution

Comment: SelectedQuoteForEditing.JobPrice value is £150.00 and lblRate.Content.ToString().ToString() value is £30.00

Comment: @user8329959: If you want to parse not just a floating pointing value (say, `150.00`) but *currency* (`£150.00`) you should let the system know this. See my edit

Comment: Thank you! I was on the right track when trying to figure this out but parse the currency in the wrong place.

Comment: As per the answer. Use this overload [public static bool TryParse (string s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider, out double result)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1):

If SelectedQuoteForEditing.JobPrice and lblRate.Content are 2 strings with the £ at the end/beginning, like 100£, 100 £ or £100. You just have to add `.Replace("£", string.Empty)` to this variable.

Comment: £ is at start like £100.00

Comment: Please, do not *hardcode* pound symbol `"£"`: your code will *stop working* in US, Russia etc. put `.Replace(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol, "");`